# What are requirements for a micropub?

Tags: terminology, micropub

So my question is what are the requirements for micropubs?
Are there any specifications on room size, interior, beers, staff?
Has anyone got experience in setting up and running a micropub and can give more insights about what are key factors?

Comment: It depends on where you are. In the U.S., you would need to comply with federal, state and local ordinances. They will vary by location.

Comment: @andrew cheong thanks for including the micropub tag

Comment: A micropub isn't a thing in my state, for what it's worth.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald A micropub is a thing, at least here in the UK. There is a mircopub association as well.

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't. I'm saying that there are very specific legal classifications for pubs and breweries in various locations and that in my location in particular "micropub" isn't even a classification. I don't know what it would be. Just a point of clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Young in terms of establishments - Micropubs "traditionally" have to adhere to certain "standards":

There is only one room
Generally too small to have a bar
No Televisions
No Juke Boxes
No manufactured (think commercialized) beer
No lagers! (Literally is a dirty word - think yelling a racial slur among the people associated with that slur)
No spirits (usually just Wine, Ale, Cider - though soft drinks and water can be supplied for children and DDs)

The focus is to shun electronics (outside of electricity) focus on social interactions and ales (and maybe sometimes pub snacks).

This seems to be a very United Kingdom centered movement (as I havent heard of this in the US).

Answer (score -2):

In the US, the "microbrewery" name is going away, and being replaced with "craft beer" as many formerly small breweries have grown so much. But they are still small compared to companies like Budweiser, Miller, Coors, etc. One [definition](https://www.brewersassociation.org/statistics/craft-brewer-defined/) is: "Annual production of 6 million barrels of beer or less..."

Beyond that, they take every conceivable form: big restaurant plus small brewery, small restaurant attached to big brewery, tasting room in an industrial park (without food), some guy's garage... whatever the local law allows.

The only constants, for businesses that last, are good beer and staff that like beer too.

Comment: Micropubs and microbreweries are two different things.